# Excel formula to find the nearest values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Is it possible to find the nearest value (+or-) with formula and display the 1st row value & 1st column value in my linked excel table?

Eg:

Search Value is "7,30" (C12; variable can ask for any value on table)

Found row value is "7" (E12 with formula; adressed to A7)

Found column value "4,00%" (E13 with formula; adressed to E1)

"F12" Formula is OK. What can be the formula in "F13" regarding the information on table below?

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv=Content-Type content="text/html; charset=Windows-1254">
<meta name=ProgId content=Excel.Sheet>
<meta name=Generator content="Microsoft Excel 14">
<link rel=File-List href="SampleT_dosyalar/filelist.xml">
<style id="table-3_9841_Styles">
<!--table
 {mso-displayed-decimal-separator:"\,";
 mso-displayed-thousand-separator:"\.";}
.xl159841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl659841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:right;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl669841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 border:.5pt solid windowtext;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl679841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:Fixed;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 border:.5pt solid windowtext;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl689841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:"0\.00\\%";
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl699841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 background:#FFC000;
 mso-pattern:black none;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl709841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:"0\.00\\%";
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 background:#FFC000;
 mso-pattern:black none;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl719841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:"0\.00\\%";
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 border:.5pt solid windowtext;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl729841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:left;
 vertical-align:top;
 border:none;
 mso-diagonal-up:.5pt solid windowtext;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:normal;}
.xl739841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:red;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:700;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl749841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:#0070C0;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:700;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl759841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:center;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 mso-background-source:auto;
 mso-pattern:auto;
 white-space:nowrap;}
.xl769841
 {padding-top:1px;
 padding-right:1px;
 padding-left:1px;
 mso-ignore:padding;
 color:black;
 font-size:11.0pt;
 font-weight:400;
 font-style:normal;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-family:Calibri, sans-serif;
 mso-font-charset:162;
 mso-number-format:General;
 text-align:general;
 vertical-align:bottom;
 background:#D9D9D9;
 mso-pattern:black none;
 white-space:nowrap;}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<!--[if !excel]>&nbsp;&nbsp;<![endif]-->
<!--Aşağıdaki bilgiler Microsoft Excel'in Web Sayfası Olarak Yayımlama
sihirbazı tarafından oluşturuldu.-->
<!--Aynı öğe Excel'den yeniden yayımlanırsa, DIV etiketleri arasındaki
bilgilerin tümü değiştirilecek.-->
<!----------------------------->
<!--EXCEL WEB SAYFASI OLARAK YAYIMLA SİHİRBAZI ÇIKTI BAŞLANGICI-->
<!----------------------------->

<div id="table-3_9841" align=center x:publishsource="Excel">

<table border=0 cellpadding=0 cellspacing=0 width=1114 style='border-collapse:
 collapse;table-layout:fixed;width:836pt'>
 <col class=xl159841 width=26 style='mso-width-source:userset;mso-width-alt:
 950;width:20pt'>
 <col class=xl159841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>
 <col width=64 span=16 style='width:48pt'>
 <tr class=xl159841 height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl769841 width=26 style='height:15.0pt;width:20pt'>&nbsp;</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>A</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>B</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>C</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>D</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>E</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>F</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>H</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>I</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>J</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>K</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>L</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>M</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>N</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>O</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>P</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>Q</td>
  <td class=xl759841 width=64 style='width:48pt'>R</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='mso-height-source:userset;height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>1</td>
  <td rowspan=2 class=xl729841 width=64 style='width:48pt'><span
  style='mso-spacerun:yes'>  </span>%<br>
    <span style='mso-spacerun:yes'>        </span>Price</td>
  <td class=xl689841 align=right>1,00%</td>
  <td class=xl689841 align=right>2,00%</td>
  <td class=xl689841 align=right>3,00%</td>
  <td class=xl709841 align=right>4,00%</td>
  <td class=xl689841 align=right>5,00%</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>2</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>3</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>3</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right><a name="RANGE!C4:G11">3,03</a></td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>3,06</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>3,095</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>3,125</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>3,16</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>4</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>4</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>4,04</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>4,08</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>4,125</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>4,165</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>4,21</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>5</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>5</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>5,05</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>5,1</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>5,155</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>5,21</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>5,265</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>6</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>6</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>6,06</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>6,12</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>6,185</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>6,25</td>
  <td class=xl739841 align=right>7,29</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>7</td>
  <td class=xl699841 align=right>7</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>7,07</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>7,145</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>7,215</td>
  <td class=xl739841 align=right>7,29</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>7,37</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>8</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>8</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>8,08</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>8,165</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>8,245</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>8,335</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>8,42</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>9</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>9</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>9,09</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>9,185</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>9,28</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>9,375</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>9,475</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>10</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>10</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>10,1</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>10,205</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>10,31</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>10,415</td>
  <td class=xl159841 align=right>10,525</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>11</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>12</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl659841>Search:</td>
  <td class=xl679841 align=right>7,30</td>
  <td class=xl659841>Row</td>
  <td class=xl669841 align=right>7</td>
  <td class=xl159841 colspan=11><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'> 
  </span>=İNDİS($A:$A;MAK((MİN(MUTLAK(DataRange-$C$12))=MUTLAK(DataRange-$C$12))*SATIR(DataRange)))</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>13</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl659841>Column</td>
  <td class=xl719841 align=right style='border-top:none'>5,00%</td>
  <td class=xl159841 colspan=11><span style='mso-spacerun:yes'> 
  </span>=İNDİS($1:$1;1;MAK((MİN(MUTLAK(DataRange-$C$12))=MUTLAK(DataRange-$C$12))*SÜTUN(DataRange)))</td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>14</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>15</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl749841 colspan=10>This formula is OK as row# &quot;7&quot; but is
  it possible to display &quot;E7&quot; instead of &quot;F6&quot; as column
  title?</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>16</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl749841 colspan=12>Can the formula check row# first to retrieve
  the colum title then check for others if no figure is identical in row
  &quot;7&quot; line?</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <tr height=20 style='height:15.0pt'>
  <td height=20 class=xl759841 style='height:15.0pt'>18</td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
  <td class=xl159841></td>
 </tr>
 <![if supportMisalignedColumns]>
 <tr height=0 style='display:none'>
  <td width=26 style='width:20pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
  <td width=64 style='width:48pt'></td>
 </tr>
 <![endif]>
</table>

</div>


<!----------------------------->
<!--EXCEL WEB SAYFASI OLARAK YAYIMLA SİHİRBAZI ÇIKTI SONU-->
<!----------------------------->
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You could create a helper table where each entry is the absolute value of C12 minus the corresponding value in your main table eg: =ABS($C$12-B3) then do a match for the Min value in that range eg: (assuming the helper table is in I3:M10) =MATCH(MIN(I7:M7),I7:M7,0). Obviously, this is specific to Row 7, I assume you already have an idea how to change rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These formulas must be **array-entered**:

```
Row:  =INDEX($A:$A,MAX((MIN(ABS(DataRange-$C$12))=ABS(DataRange-$C$12))*ROW(DataRange)))

Column:  =INDEX($1:$1,1,MAX((MIN(ABS(DataRange-$C$12))=ABS(DataRange-$C$12))*COLUMN(DataRange)))
```

**EDIT:** If there is a possibility of duplicates in the table (two values that are equidistant from the search value, then the following formula will ensure that `Column` comes from the same row as the row value found.

```
Row:  Formula in C12
Column:  =INDEX($1:$1,1,MAX((MIN(ABS(INDEX(DataRange,E12-ROW(DataRange)+1,0)-$C$12))=ABS(INDEX(DataRange,E12-ROW(DataRange)+1,0)-$C$12))*COLUMN(DataRange)))
```

In your example,

```
DataRange refers to:    =Sheet1!$B$3:$F$10
```

---

To **array-enter** a formula, after entering
the formula into the cell or formula bar, hold down
<kbd>ctrl+shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you did this
correctly, Excel will place braces <kbd>**{...}**</kbd> around the formula.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. Thanks so much

Comment: At my further checkings I noticed that the requested percentage by the 2nd formula E13) can be preceeded from the row retrieved by the 1st formula if there are same figures in table. I mean, suppose 7,29 is located both in F6 & E7 so the 1st formula will display E7 priority but 2nd formula will display F6 (5%) as a matter of indexing.

Comment: @ZRS Provide an example that can be copied/pasted (not a screenshot) and also what you want for results if there are duplicate matches in the table. Duplicates could also occur with two different but equidistant values in the table. Do this by editing your original post.

Comment: I wonder the possibility if 2nd formula checks 1st formula retrieved row# (A7) priority and display column header if figure is met in that line of rows otherwise bring the header from first matched row. I will try to edit my original post as you recommended. Thanks again

Comment: @ZRS See my Edit for a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I guess there must be a prettier answer to this, but this worked for me:
In E12 put this:

```
=ROUNDDOWN(C12,0)
```

And in E13 put this Array-Formula (need to be entered with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`Enter` instead of the usual `Enter`):

```
=MATCH(MIN(ABS(C12-B3:F10)),ABS(C12-INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("B",E12)):INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("F",E12))),0)
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In E12, the row:

```
=INDEX(A:A,AGGREGATE(15,6,($B$3:$F$10)/(AGGREGATE(15,6,ABS(C12-$B$3:$F$10),1)=ABS(C12-$B$3:$F$10)),1))
```

In E13, the column:

```
=INDEX(1:1,AGGREGATE(15,6,COLUMN($B$3:$F$10)/(AGGREGATE(15,6,ABS(C12-$B$3:$F$10),1)=ABS(C12-$B$3:$F$10)),1))
```

[image]